# org.Testng.Exception: Class is not found in classpath[class name] whenever I run any test

Tags: testng

I have tried with going into Eclipse -> Project -> Clean but still it is not working.  Please see error and error log below.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your project through Eclipse, May be you haven't put your configuration correctly, I suggest, go to Eclipse -> Run -> Run Configuration -> Main -> and specify correct classpath there.